# Unable to update an entity with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm having some trouble with this exception from springboot :
identifier of an instance of Association was altered from Association@42c3ddac to Association@5f8c91f9.

I don't really understand why i'm having this exception since i'm only saving an object while changing a non key attribute using this method :

```java
@PutMapping("/accept")
    public ResponseEntity<SoumissionDto> setAssociationToAccepted(@RequestBody AssociationDto associationDto) {
        try {
            Canvas canvas = canvasService.getCanvasByCodeInvitation(associationDto.getCodeInvitation());
            Canvas canvasSoumis = canvasService.getCanvasById(associationDto.getGuidcanvasIndividuel());
            Association updatedAssociation = associationService.getAssociationByCanvasCollabAndCanvas(canvas.getGUIDCanvas(), canvasSoumis.getGUIDCanvas());
            if (updatedAssociation == null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            } else {
                System.out.println("j'ai eu cette asso id :  "+ updatedAssociation.getCanvas().getGUIDCanvas().toString() +"  id collab  " + updatedAssociation.getCanvasEquipe().getGUIDCanvas().toString());
                updatedAssociation.setStatut(true);
                
Association returnAssociation = associationService.updateAssociation(updatedAssociation);
                SoumissionDto soumissionDto = createSoumissionDtoFromAssociation(returnAssociation);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(soumissionDto, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("J'ai une erreur : "+e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("stack : "+ Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
            System.out.println("cause : "+e.getCause());

            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Association POJO :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Association")
@IdClass(Association.class)
public class Association {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "canvas_collectif", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Canvas canvas_collectif;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "canvas", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Canvas canvas;


    @Column(name = "statut", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private boolean statut;
//with the usual getter and setter
}
```

In my database, the association uses a key composed of the canvas id and the canvas_collaboratifId and has a boolean attribute name statut.

With this method, i'm aiming to change the statut attribut to true

I don't understand why i can't save my association since i don't even touch on of the ids...

Thanks for your time
Have a nice day guys

EDIT 1 : here is the stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:321),
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233),
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566),
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743),
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711),
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654),
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407),
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184),
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184),
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184),
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184),
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218),
jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy125.save(Unknown Source),
com.cogiteo.canvas.entitiescontroller.association.service.AssociationService.updateAssociation(AssociationService.java:33),
com.cogiteo.canvas.entitiescontroller.association.controller.AssociationController.setAssociationToAccepted(AssociationController.java:84),
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77),
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568),
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207),
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152),
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117),
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884),
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797),
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87),
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080),
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973),
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003),
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:917),
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734),
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880),
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158),
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158),
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100),
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158),
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93),
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158),
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201),
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185),
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97),
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119),
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92),
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78),
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357),
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400),
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65),
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861),
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739),
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52),
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191),
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659),
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61),
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: When asking about exceptions it's always good to post the stack trace here as it may contain information to that helps understand the cause. Just the message may not be sufficient.

Comment: One thing you might want to look for is transaction boundaries. If you return an entity from a call that is wrapped in its own transaction (and by extension Hibernate session) the returned entity will become attached. Updating it subsequently will require a merge and that's what might not be happening in your case. That being said I don't see any transaction demarcation on your code which may indicate that `getAssociationByCanvasCollabAndCanvas()` and `updateAssociation()` are using different transactions - controllers are non-transactional by default.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found a solution,
since i was using a composite key, i needed to create a class Association_PK implementing Serializable and declare it in Association.
Here are the classes :

```
package com.cogiteo.canvas.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Association_PK implements Serializable {
    private long canvas_collectif;
    private long canvas;

    public Association_PK() {
    }

    public Association_PK(long canvas_collectif, long canvas) {
        this.canvas_collectif = canvas_collectif;
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }
}
```

and the updated Association :

```
package com.cogiteo.canvas.entities;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.IdClass;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Association")
@IdClass(Association_PK.class)
public class Association {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "canvas_collectif", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Canvas canvas_collectif;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "canvas", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Canvas canvas;


    @Column(name = "statut", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private boolean statut;


    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public boolean getStatut() {
        return statut;
    }

    public void setStatut(boolean statut) {
        this.statut = statut;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvasEquipe() {
        return canvas_collectif;
    }

    public void setCanvasEquipe(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas_collectif = canvas;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time everyone !
Have a nice day !